# collecting specific component statistics in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I would like to collect useful statistics in ejabberd.

Let's say I would be interested in knowing how many messages were sent to one or more specific internal components, what is in your opinion the best between these two solutions?

1. Set up a new component (based on gen_mod + gen_server) with a filter_packet hook and handle in a specific function all the messages directed towards the aforesaid components. In order to not bother the message forwarding I could spawn a function to route asap the message and then log easily the data in this component using some ets/mnesia/mysql table.
2. Log the data when I actually receive it in the component of interest.

Can you tell me which solution is the best?

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to have a mechanism to diagnose the system in production, I think that you could use a gen_event server to which you can connect, permanently or temporarily one or several event handler. The draw back is that you have to generate the events in your current code.

[image: example of supervision tree using a gen_event]

If the purpose is to profile/analyze your application, you should look at existing tools such as observer, pman...

EDIT:

The interest of gen_event is that it is a ready made behavior allowing to connect several event handlers on demand.

pman allows you to see all the message sent, message receive and function call of a process. They are given as follow by default, I didn't check if it is possible to add other information such as timestamp, and what can be filtered or not.

```
...
<0.60.0>: call  erlang:spawn_link(erlang, apply, [#Fun<util.3.13553350>,[]])
{trace,<0.60.0>,spawn,<0.180.0>,{erlang,apply,[#Fun<util.3.13553350>,[]]}}
<0.60.0>: link  <0.180.0>
<0.60.0>: call  erlang:now()
<0.60.0>: call  gen_event:notify(plc1, {store, t5_plc1, running, 1360156073108})
<0.60.0>: call  gen_event:send(plc1, {notify, {store, t5_plc1, running, 1360156073108}})
<0.60.0>:  !    To: plc1 Msg: {notify, {store, t5_plc1, running, 1360156073108}}
<0.60.0>: call  erlang:setelement(12, {state, t5_plc1, #Fun<testmngr.9.27375888>, #Fun<testmngr.10.27375888>, 46, forever, 0, 1, run, undefined, undefined, <0.179.0>, plc1}, <0.180.0>)
<0.180.0>: call  erlang:apply(#Fun<util.3.13553350>, [])
<0.180.0>: rec   timeout
<0.180.0>: call  gen_server:cast(manager_plc1, {complete, t5_plc1})
<0.180.0>: call  gen_server:do_cast(manager_plc1, {complete, t5_plc1})
<0.180.0>: call  gen_server:cast_msg({complete, t5_plc1})
<0.180.0>: call  gen_server:do_send(manager_plc1, {'$gen_cast', {complete, t5_plc1}})
<0.180.0>: call  erlang:send(manager_plc1, {'$gen_cast', {complete, t5_plc1}}, [noconnect])
<0.180.0>:  !    To: manager_plc1 Msg: {'$gen_cast', {complete, t5_plc1}}
<0.180.0>:  !    To: <0.60.0> Msg: {'$gen_event', {complete, 47}}
<0.60.0>: rec   {'$gen_event', {complete, 47}}
<0.180.0>: exit   normal
<0.60.0>: getting_unlinked   <0.180.0>
...
```

Comment: AFAIK observer and pman are not the solution because they can not provide info on XMPP packets handled by ejabberd. events handler are just another possibility to handle parsed data, but this sata comes from solution1 or solution2